# viewmodel and scaffolding migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a multiple options select for my dropdown menu. I am able to get the listbox working fine, however, I am trying to store the selected items so I tried using a viewmodel to store it as a collection, however, my `.cshtml` file was already calling the db model, so I couldn't include the viewmodel in the `.cshtml` file since a view can only have one model.... also even when I tried just calling the viewmodel in my `.cshtml` using other means, it kept saying the collection was null exception error...

So following this wonderful [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Irr7oLEMAR8) video tutorial I decided to bring the `ICollection` to my existing model like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries{ get; set; }
```

Everything was smooth until it said, i should do a database migration because the model has changed.

Due to security reasons, I need to send any update queries to the sysadmin to run any table changes against the database, so my question is, what is really happening when I use

```
 public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries{ get; set; }
```

What is changing in my existing table? What am I altering? And if nothing is changing, then how come I need to do a db migration for this to take effect? Each time I run update-database in the package manager console, I get an error which says I don't have permissions (an error I am familiar with, which requires me to send table changes to the sysadmin)

Any ideas where to store my collection, in the viewmodel or the model. The youtube example shows in the model?

Comment: The return Type from your dropdown list is a class or a primitive type? Because if it is a primitive type there is a simple solution for your problem

Comment: what will the solution be if it is primitive type, i want a solution that will not include db migration, however, i think i might need to do db migration since i will be storing a collection of countries associated with a person, unless this storage will happen in the virtual icollection in the viewmodel?

Comment: If it is a primitive type you give each select that you want to get value from a name (myvalues for example) and in the post method you define an `ICollection<Country> myvalues` as a parameter for the method

Comment: I got it working!!! all i needed to do was to add a single line of code to my model to state which variable is the foreign key: [ForeignKey("Country")]

Answer (score 0):

When you add a property like:

```
public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries{ get; set; }
```

Then a foreign key needs to be added on the table backing `Country` to point to the model that has this property.

I'm not sure what problem exactly you're having using view models, but it's pretty straight-forward. Just add whatever properties you need to edit from your model to the view model and then make the view model the model for the view.

If you got an error saying a collection is null, then you need to initialize the collection. Again, this is all pretty basic stuff here. You can either do it in the constructor of your view model, manually in your action, etc. Whatever makes the most sense for your application.

Then, for a select list, you must remember that the value that will be posted is going to be a scalar type: string, int, etc. You can't directly post to something that expects a class like `Country` because the modelbinder will have no idea how to instantiate `Country` based on the posted value. Usually, what you would do is use the `Id` as the value of the option, and then in your post action, use the id values to look up the actual objects from the database, before finally attaching those to your model.

**View Model**

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public FooViewModel()
    {
        SelectedCountryIds = new List<int>();
    }

    ...

    public List<int> SelectedCountryIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryChoices { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
private void PopulateCountryChoices(FooViewModel model)
{
    model.CountryChoices = db.Countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.Id.ToString(),
        Text = m.Name
    });
}

public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new FooViewModel();

    PopulateCountryChoices(model);

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(FooViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var foo = new Foo
        {
            // map properties from view model
            Countries = db.Countries.Where(m => model.SelectedCountryIds.Contains(m.Id))
        }

        db.Foos.Add(foo);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirecToAction("Index");
    }

    // Posted form has errors
    PopulateCountryChoices(model);
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model Namespace.To.FooViewModel

...

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCountryIds, Model.CountryChoices)
```

Comment: this is the part I needed clarification: "Then a foreign key needs to be added on the table backing Country to point to the model that has this property." thanks, now i understand the db migration has to happen. got it!

Comment: it just occurred to me the foreign key already exist and yet i need to do db migration? why can't the db/code already figure out it already exist?

Comment: Well, without being able to see your full code and schema, I can't say for sure, but it's not enough that a foreign key exists, it has to be the right foreign key to the right table with the right column name that EF is expecting. There's ways to customize a lot of that if you need to, but for whatever reason EF determined it didn't have what it needed.

Comment: I got it working, took me the whole after and all i needed to do was to add a single line of code to my model to state which variable is the foreign key: [ForeignKey("Country")]!!!!